# Sphero 3.0 / absolute tracking / STEM System

Tags: position, tracking, sphero-api

Is there any chance that in future versions of Sphero absolute tracking gets implemented?
Could be archived with the STEM System from Sixsense I'm sure they would license it.

Comment: Well I never heard of STEM until this post but it looks like a neat solution. I saw a review of the hydra controller an it did sound like it has some limitations based on where the electro-magnetic emitter is  directed. The magnetic fields from the Sphero motor may also interfere, which is the reason the magnetometer in Sphero isn't always used.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands, we are always trying to make the Sphero track better so all who use it can do bigger and better things, but we also have to balance that with the end cost of the ball. Adding the chipsets needed to provide the same technology licensed by STEM would cause the ball to become extremely costly to end users.

That being said, somewhere down the line we may implement absolute tracking with the ball if the correct opportunity were to present itself.

There is nothing stopping developers or hackers from trying it themselves though!